# Modifying ground-truth values in loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a regression problem, using Keras on top of TensorFlow. Given an input vector 
[x_1, ..., x_n], the task is to predict an output vector [y_1, ..., y_n].
I use a simple Fully Connected Network with relu activation, and a mean squared error as a loss function.

My problem is that the ground-truth is incomplete : i.e, some output vectors are not fully annotated. When a value of a vector is not annotated, the given value is 0. For example, we can have y = [54, 0, 3].

Thus, I want the loss function to not penalize the network trying to predict the real value. My idea was to change the values of the ground truth to the value predicted by the network during training, so the loss is null for the non-annotated points - something like :

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    for i in range(0,len(y_true)):
        if y_true[i] == 0:
            y_true[i] = y_true[pred]
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

But as we are dealing with tensors, it seems we can not change their values that easily. Is it somehow possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the other way around is easier. Multiply your predicted values by the exact zero you have, and the gradients for that element will simply not propagate.

```
def customLoss(true,pred):

    nonZeroTrue = K.cast(K.not_equal(true,0),K.floatx())
    maskedPred = pred * nonZeroTrue

    return anyStandardLoss(true,maskedPred)
```

Where `anyStandardLoss` may be, for 'mse':

```
K.mean(K.square(maskedPred - true), axis=-1)
```

You can import loss functions from `keras.losses` and use there too.